# get repositoryItemGridLookupEdit parent's currentrow processed

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridlookupedit

I have a Gridview and a RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit in that GridView
I want to show a CustomDisplayText in the RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit

```
private void rgluePerson_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
        {
            var person = rgluePerson.GetRowByKeyValue(e.Value) as Person;
            var name = person.Name;
            var surname = person.Surname;
            e.DisplayText = name + ", " + surname;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the person name depends of another cell in the same row (in the main Gridview), and i don't know how to get the current's Gridview row being processed (current row doesn't work since i need the row being processed in the moment)...... i can't use a gridView event cuz it will change the cell value, but i want to change the Text value.
Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Use the GetSelectedRows method to check if a row is being processed

Comment: I tryed gridView3.GetSelectedRows() inside CustomDisplayText Event and it doesn't get the row being processed by the event.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the row being processed by the `CustomDisplayText` event because there are no such fields or properties that contains current row. You can only use this event for focused row. For this your must check if sender is type of `GridLookUpEdit`:

```
private void rgluePerson_CustomDisplayText(object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is GridLookUpEdit))
        return;

    var anotherCellValue = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("AnotherCellFieldName");

    //Your code here

    e.DisplayText = yourDisplayText;        
}
```

For not focused rows you can use only [`ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) event:

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.ColumnEdit != rgluePerson)
        return;

    var anotherCellValue = gridView1.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "AnotherCellFieldName");

    //Your code here

    e.DisplayText = yourDisplayText; 
}
```

Comment: Thanx! The second event is what i was looking for. the rgluePerson events made me confuse a bit